# Flask Python - basic program does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, pycharm

I wrote this super basic application. It runs but does not do a thing:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return "<h1>Hello!</h1>"


if __name__ == "__name__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The console shows:

> C:\Users\TalT\PycharmProjects\FlaskBeginners\venv\Scripts\python.exe
> C:/Users/TalT/PycharmProjects/FlaskBeginners/MyFirstWebPage.py
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I work on Win10, PyCharm 2019.3.3 and Python 3.7 .
I don't understand where is the problem? Is it a python issue or maybe project configuration?

Comment: `if __name__ == "__name__":` should be `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Well spotted @CoryNezin

Comment: @CoryNezin hahah... Thank you! It really had some itches in my eye because of this but I couldn't spot it out. Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem!  Admittedly it took me a while to spot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
if __name__ == "__name__":
```

Must change to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

To start a flask app you have 2 easy different ways.

**1.** Rename your main file to `app.py` or `wsgi.py` and go to path of the file in terminal and type `flask run`. In this way, if you want to run app in **debug mode**, In the same path, type `set FLASK_ENV=development` in terminal (Windows) and then write `flask run`.

**Tip:** In this way, you must **delete** the following code from your project:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**2.** Write your code in a python file (name is **not matter**) for example with `main.py` name write like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG']=True

@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return '<h1>Hello!</h1>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And run the application by running this command in the path of your file: `python main.py` . Remember, add this code `app.config['DEBUG']=True` only if you want to run your code in debug mode.